# Why does my wireless network disappear every 15 seconds?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a PC with (secured) wireless Internet configured. This works fine, for a while.

Then suddenly, halfway through the evening, **the connection is lost and is back again** in a second or so. Windows then tries to recover by acquiring a new IP address. But before this is resolved, **15 seconds later, the connection is dropped again**. This process repeats itself indefinitely. Windows is forever trying to acquire an IP address, and the connection drops and recovers every 15 seconds.

Strangely enough, when I try my netbook at the same time, it has no problems with connectivity. But it doesn't seem PC-related, because **I have exactly the same problem on a third computer**. It just seems that one computer is more sensitive to the problem than others.

Also, when I check my PC the next morning, everything works fine again.

Note: I changed the default channel (7) in the wireless modem to 11 and to 3, but **changing the channel didn't improve things in any way**.

What else could be the problem?

PS: I have a Sitecom Wireless Network PCI Adapter MiMoXR WL-151
And a ZyXEL modem.
And Windows XP.

(Same on both computers that are giving problems)

Comment: Please specify operating system and hardware (wireless card & driver) of the systems you tested it with.

Comment: Are you in an airplane flying loops above your house when this happens?

Answer (score 2):

If both computers that drop it have the same network card, that could be your culprit. Have you tried updating the drivers?

Answer (score 1):

One other possible culprit - do you have the SSID on the wireless set to broadcast?  I had one computer on my network that ALWAYS had problems with my wireless.  The problem was that I was NOT broadcasting the SSID (a lame attempt at helping to keep my network secure (with other items, of course)).  Once I switched the broadcast back on, *poof*!  Problem went away.

The main point was, it did NOT affect every computer in the same way.  Just the one had problems with it - others (some running the same OS, virtually the same hardware) did not have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought (and maybe more of a hack than a fix), have you tried setting static IPs on the machines that keep dropping the connections?

Comment: No, but thanks for the suggestion. I will try that.